# Joomla 1.6 question about incorporating PivotViewer for Joomla Extension

Tags: silverlight, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

I really think my problem in this case stems from a lack of understanding about Joomla and not the PivotViewer Component (http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/pivotviewer/) which I am trying to install.

The component adds a bit of macro code into an article, but when I publish, the article just displays the macro text and does not execute the macro.  What results is an article with this text:

```
{pivotviewer id="5" name="MarkBrandon"}</p>"</p>"
```

This code is supposed to render a Silverlight PivotViewer control.  Have I utilized the WYSIWYG editor in such a way as to prevent rendering of the macro?  I have scoured over the Component documentation to see if I have done anything wrong.  I am using a localhost via Microsoft WebMatrix, IIS 7.5, .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I found that it is a problem with the PivotViewer control not being able to serve in a local host environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to ensure that the plugin is activated? It is not automatically activated when installed. Also you say it is a component, however the call {pivotviewer id="5" name="MarkBrandon"} is for a plugin, maybe you still need to install this plugin as you ave only installed the component.